# Three Dimensional Output Loss

Tags: python, keras

I am currently working on implementing a time series prediction task that will produce labels across a sequence (batch, steps, features) -> (batch, steps, classes). I have a TimeDistributed layer as my final layer and have a three dimensional output due to this, I seem to be getting terrible accuracy. I am wondering if this is due to the three dimensional output not being calculated correctly in the loss. Is there a better way to do this?

```
K.clear_session()

def acc(y_true, y_pred):
    y_pred = tf.argmax(y_pred, 2)
    y_true = tf.squeeze(y_true, -1)
    return categorical_accuracy(y_true, y_pred)

def loss(labels, logits):
    return tf.keras.losses.sparse_categorical_crossentropy(labels, logits, from_logits=True)

def build_model():
    char_in = Input(shape=(None, None)) #sequence length, word char length
    char_emb = Embedding(char_emb_weights.shape[1], 32, weights=char_emb_weights, trainable=False)(char_in)
    char_GRU = TimeDistributed(Bidirectional(GRU(32, recurrent_initializer='glorot_uniform'), 'concat'))(char_emb)
    lstm = LSTM(64, return_sequences=True, recurrent_initializer='glorot_uniform')(char_GRU)
    dense = TimeDistributed(Dense(16, activation='relu'))(lstm)
    output = TimeDistributed(Dense(3, activation='softmax'))(dense)
    #output = CRF(target_size, sparse_target=True)(dense)
    m = Model(inputs=[word_in, char_in], outputs=output)
    m.compile(optimizer='sgd', loss=loss, metrics=[acc])
    return m
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue, using a model with lower hidden nodes per layer reduced model complexity and allowed for convergence.

That being said, I am still looking for an explanation as to why this is and also I am curious about a three dimensional output and how loss is calculated over time if anyone can provide an answer.